# React JS, error in Redux state updation, cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

When I update the redux state it gives error *TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))*

```
const initialState = {
  articles: []
};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
 switch(action.type){
   case ADD_ARTICLE:{return [...state,action.payload];}  # error occurs in this line
   default:return state;
 }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to clone the state which is `{}` and not `[]`. Try to return as the following:

```
switch(action.type) {
   case ADD_ARTICLE: {
     return {
        ...state,
        action.payload
     };
   }

   default: {
     return ...state;
   }
}
```

Comment: case ADD_ARTICLE:{return {articles:[...state.articles,action.payload]}}
small correction